# Pug Form POST Body Empty When Submitting

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a pug file with a form that send a POST request to a NodeJS endpoint, the endpoint will receive the request, but not the values in body.

pug form

```
form(action='/user_metricPOST', method='POST')
      input(type='text', name='user')
      input(type='text', name='start')
      input(type='text', name='end')
      input(type='submit', value='Search')
```

html source

```
<form action="/user_metricPOST" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="user">
  <input type="text" name="start">
  <input type="text" name="end">
  <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

nodejs POST

```
server.post('/user_metricPOST', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

output

```
{}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: @Graham just edited the post with the info

Comment: Try using [urlencoded body-parser](http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#bodyparserurlencodedoptions)

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek Thanks so much! I used that to fix my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to @SebastianKaczmarek I figured out that adding this to my code fixed the problem!

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
server.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Comment: Glad I could help ;)